# Does a deep sea electric ray creature sound plausible?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, fauna

I was making a species for a school project and would like to know if my idea is plausible. It is kind of barebones though.

I was thinking of a deep sea electric ray that uses its tail as a sort of light to lure prey along with the ability to electrical and stun those prey also. I don't have all the specifics of the light and everything else figured out but have been taking ideas from anywhere I could find.

Thank You!

Comment: Sounds plausible is the epitome of a subjective question of the sort not permitted on this site.

Answer (score 2):

There are [fish which use a luminous appendage to lure prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish), for example the [humpback anglerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpback_anglerfish) *Melanocetus johnsonii*. There are [fish which use electric discharges to stun prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_ray), for example the [marbled electric ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marbled_electric_ray) *Torpedo marmorata*. A fish which uses a luminous appendage to lure prey and then uses an electric discharge to stun it is entirely possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll check those out and see if I can I get the technicalities down next.